# is there a shell-command-at-point

Tags: shell-command, point

This is a bit of a long shot, but I'm going to ask anyway.
Kinda similar to what `dired-at-point` and `find-file-at-point`

When point is inside a `.txt` file on a line like this

```
ls -la /tmp/
```

When point is at the beginning of that line, is there something like `shell-command-at-point` where the shell command on that line is executed and the output is displayed in the echo area?  The other way to do it is I guess to yank the line, `M-| paste RET`.

I think Org mode has this feature `[[shell:ls -la /tmp/][example]`, but I'm looking for a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this with point anywhere on the line.  If you really need a command that acts only on the rest of the line, starting at point, then substitute `(point)` for `(line-beginning-position)`.

```el
(defun foo (&optional output-buffer error-buffer)
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (let ((strg  (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position) 
                                               (line-end-position))))
    (shell-command strg output-buffer error-buffer)))
```